# how to show a column thats removed by a group by in sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Please see my query below. How can i set it up to return the 1 subobject that has the max age. if i group by subobject, then it shows all of them

```
select 
object,
max(Age) as Age,
from table
group by 1,
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What if multiple rows have the same maximum age?

Comment: good question. i didn't consider that. i just need to show one. doesn't matter which one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try The below

```
;with cte as
(
select  Object,SubObject,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Object order by age desc) as rowNum
from table
)
select * from cte where rowNum=1
```

Comment: this works, thank you! i am trying to adjust it now to work with another aggregation. in the results screenshot, i also have another col right now that is "count (subobject) as number_of_subobjects.,", that doesnt work anymore with the above. i tried "select  *, count (subobject) as number_of_subobjects,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Object order by age desc) as rowNum" line but it comes in as 1

Comment: use this select *,Count(subobject) over (Partition by Object) as numberOfSubjects,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Object order by age desc) as rowNum"

Answer (score 1):

You can use an analytic function (`MAX OVER`):

```
select *
from
(
  select t.*, max(age) over (partition by object) as max_age
  from table t
) with_max_age
where age = max_age
order by object;
```

Comment: hi, the "with_max_age" doesn't seem to work in redshift for me

Comment: That's weird. It's just an alias for the derived table aka subquery. This is the same as using a `WITH` clause as shown in Eid Morsy's answer. And `ROW_NUMBER` is as good as `MAX` here and in other situations where you have a more complex ranking order it's even better. I'm glad Eid Morsy's answer worked for you.